# How to unselect radio button selection in form?

Tags: forms, symfony

Actually I display a field of many projects with radio button. This option is not required so I would to be able to reset the project selection (like checkbox but without multiple selection).

```
# MyNiceBundle/Form/Type/TsakType.php
// This code display all project with radio button
$builder->add('project', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'MyNiceBundle:Project',
    'property' => 'name',
    'multiple' => false,
    'required' => false,
    'expanded' => true,
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->innerJoin('p.collaborations', 'pc')
            ->andWhere('pc.participant = :participant')
            ->setParameter('participant', $user);
    })
);
```

Is there an option to do that or I need to use an another widget?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Actually a selectable, empty value should be displayed in this case (like with "expanded" => false). Unfortunately, this is a known bug and not fixed yet: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3154

Comment: Is there an extern widget to do same things?